# Unit Tests VS 2013 - Manifest references file 'vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.exe' which is not part of the payload

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

I am working on a Windows 8.1 Store App and I created Unit Tests. Last week everything worked out fine, but since a few days I am not able to build my Unit-Test-Projects.

Every Unit-Test-Project has the following two errors:

- Manifest references file 'vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.exe' which is not part of the payload. [PathToTest].Logic.Tests\Package.appxmanifest
- Manifest references file 'vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe' which is not part of the payload. [PathToTest].Logic.Tests\Package.appxmanifest

I already tried to re-install VS 2013 with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by recreating all UnitTestLibraries and moving the existing CodeFiles from the old UnitTestLibraries into the new UnitTestLibraries.

Comment: Or, you could have just fixed the manifest.  See http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/10/09/how-to-resolve-the-manifest-reference-file-xyz-is-not-part-of-the-payload-in-metro.aspx and http://visualstudiofeeds.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=12920

Answer (score 1):

Run the Visual Studio 2013 setup, and select the Repair option. I had the exact same issue a couple of days ago. I have tried everything, but even a new test project, with no code, was failing. After the repair it is working fine.

My guess is that some extension, SDK, or even the VS 2015 community may have corrupted something.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem by moving to VS 2015, recreating did unfortunately not help

Answer (score 0):

Execute Visual Studio installer and run repair.